# Create View character or word count limitations & workaround with phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Are there any word or character count limits in creating a view in phpMyAdmin? I have a long SELECT statement with some complex JOIN statements included. It executes, but when I attempt to "Create View", the "Cancel" & "Go" buttons do not appear.

Shorter SELECT statements don't have an issue. The SELECT statement I have is 947 characters & 138 words.

I have found that cutting this query down to 107 words / 742 characters which will still execute does produce the "Cancel" & "Go" buttons for creating a view in phpMyAdmin. But doing so excludes some desired information. Does anyone know the limitation regarding this?

It would be nice to store this as a view. I am not confident as making it a function yet.

Ah! I found a work around! It worked for me! All 947 characters / 138 words!

1. Create the SELECT query
2. Copy & paste the entire query into a text editor
3. Shorten the query to a length where it will execute
4. Select "Create View"
5. If the "Cancel" & "Go" buttons DO NOT APPEAR, repeat step 3, above.
   else
6. Copy the entire SELECT query from the text editor, into the "AS" box.

(The "Create View" light box may enlarge so much as to shift the complete browser page so the light box is off screen. Scroll to find it again. [Safari browser: Version 9.1.1 (11601.6.17)])

7. Select the "Go" button.

I am apologize for wasting everyone's time on this.

Comment: Have you tried to create the view in the cli mysql client? Not sure, but it might be that PhpMyAdmin is timing out on long operations.

Comment: No, but that is not far from my mind. I am green at setting up CLI & Secure Shell. I used to work in CLI years ago, but SQL is new to me & the GUI gets me through a subject I barely understand. I am going to get some help with CLI pronto. It can't be that difficult. Thanks.